# Why does the template order matter in this code?

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming

I wrote a test program for playing with templates. The program is intended to simulate a way to create generic objects that box any type(eg an object boxing an int would be object<int>).

I want to be able to print these boxed objects without implementing specific asString operations, since the underlying types already know how to print themselves via stringstream(or if they don't, they can implement it), so I want to avoid duplicate code.

I managed to get it working, but if I change the order of the two templated asString functions, the program no longer compiles.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>

/* an object in the set(type) T */
template <typename T>
struct object {
    T identity;

    object(T t) {
        this->identity = t;
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::string asString(T t) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << t;
    return s.str();    
}

template <typename T>
std::string asString(object<T> obj) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << asString(obj.identity);
    return s.str();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    object<int> a = 3;
    puts(asString(a).c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain why the order that the two asString function definitions matters?

Comment: Sounds like the second one has a reference to the first one at asString(obj.identity).... that's why !

Comment: Ok I added a forward declaration `template <typename T> std::string asString(T t);` and it worked. You're right.

Comment: As `obj.identity` is a `T`, rather than an `object<T>`, the first overload is needed for the call to `asString(obj.identity);`.